# D&D 4e Campaigns/Adventures that spell things out for a brand new DM

Tags: dnd-4e, game-recommendation, published-adventures

I am brand new to D&D I bought the Player's Handbook, DM Guide and Monster Manuel.. Along with Monster Vault and The Dungeon Master's Kit.. I also got the Starter Red Box... What I am looking for is a complete beginner adventure. I have one that I downloaded called Shadowfell I believe but I have read it and its not really a Step by Step it lays it out but gives you not much but maybe a few paragraphs for a story. Is there nothing out there more descriptive ?

Comment: So you're not looking for any canned adventure,  you're looking for something almost more like the old Red Box intro solo adventure, that totally holds your hand and says "Blah blah happens, now roll X here."

Comment: Welcome to the site! Please take a look at the [tour](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/about) and the [help](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/help); they're a useful introduction to the site. And once you have 20+ rep, feel free to [join the chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11/rpg-general-chat)!

Comment: Ok. Before I edit my answer, taking Keep on the Shadowfell as an example. It does lay it out, it tells you when to roll initiative, when to say "you see.." etc. So can you please clarify exactly what you mean by "Step By Step". if you're looking for "They see X, roll int, they attack with power X" then it's not going to happen, there's far too many combinations as to what they can do, it's down to them to say "can I..." and the DM saying "Yes, but you need to roll...". 
This is where the player cards come in handy for 4e, it assists in what you can do

Comment: You could also find one that you like, and then hop on chat and get someone experienced with 4e to clear up anything you don't understand.

Comment: In many ways it is easier to run a few one-session mini adventures of your own design. Just pick a setting, describe a place in it that the characters are, pick a few monsters out of the manual following the DMG rules, and keep it simple until you get the swing of making stuff up on the fly. (yes... You CAN push that statue over on the goblins.. Role Strength... Uh... It crushes one of the goblins flat. SQUISH!!!)

Answer (score 3):

There are many adventures from Wizards of the Coast already, although not EVERY check is detailed, specific guides are in place. There are also a lot of them given out free :)

Anything without the dragon symbol next to it is freely available for download: [D&D Adventure Archive](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/archive.aspx?category=all&subcategory=adventures)

Edit: Ah I knew I'd seen it

[THIS Adventure is the Gencon 2010 Celebrity game by Chris Perkins](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/KillMessengers.pdf)

And [here's video 1](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Iy8-NNlE80A) of it being played (and run by Chris Perkins himself) so you can look at how to run it